# symbolic differentiation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, differentiation

I'm new at Haskell-programming and have to do some excercises for my functional development lecture at the university. I got the task to create a datatype, called "term" which represents a rational function. The second task is to create a method which differentiates the entered term.

We need a simple solution and constructors for: monomial, Addition, Multiplication, divison

Given:

```
 data Term = Monom (Int, Int) | Addition[Term] deriving Show
    diff :: Term -> Term
    diff (Monom(a, b)) = Monom(a*b, b-1)
```

Edit:

Calling the following function will return the corresponsing derivation:

```
diff (Monom(a,b)) = if b>0 then Monom(a*b, b-1) else Monom(0,0)
```

same for:

```
diff (Addition(x:xs)) = diff(x)
```

Can anyone tell me how to iterate over all elements in the entered list? The function above returns only the first derivated value..

I appreciate every help or hint!

Comment: Well first you should think about **how you will represent a rational function**...

Comment: ....in such a way that it will contain all of the information required for easy differentiation..

Comment: You should really explain how your `Term` is supposed to represent a rational function; that's quite unclear. It looks more like a representation of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell has an extremely expressive type system. Don't over think it! Just write a type that can simply capture the definition of a rational function. Since a rational function `f(x)` is a function that can be written in the form `p(x)/q(x)` for polynomials `p(x)` and `q(x)`, all your rational function type needs to do is encompass is two polynomials:

```
data Polynomial = undefined -- your HW here

data RationalFunction = Polynomial Polynomial

-- or

data RationalFunction = { numerator :: Polynomial
                        , denominator :: Polynomial
                        }
```

Comment: With the guidelines of our professor we got the following as far as now:

data Term = Monom(Int, Int)
                    | Addition[Term] deriving Show;

diff :: Term -> Term
diff (Monom(a, b)) = Monom(a*b, b-1)

Our struggle is to add the function for the differentiation of a sum. Can you help us with that?

Comment: I see. Your original question says you are tasked with creating a datatype, but your comment here indicates that the datatypes are already created, you are simply implementing the rest of the function `diff` so that it works with all values of type `Term`. I would update your original question, work out the actual logic for subtracting rational functions (or look it up), and then ask a more precise question regarding the Haskell syntax for how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add to the definition of `diff`. It has already been defined for one of the two constructors of the `Term` type, `Monom`. You now need to define it for the other constructor, `Addition`:

```
diff (Monom (a, b)) = Monom (a*b, b-1)
diff (Addition terms) = ???
```

Think about what the derivative of a polynomial is: the sum of the derivatives of the individual terms.

1)  `d/dx x^2 + x == 2*x + 1`

Now think about how the above polynomial is represented as a `Term` value:

2 ) `Addition [Monom (1,2), Monom (1, 1)]   -- x^2 + x`

And finally, how would the derivative be represented?

3) `Addition [Monom(2, 1),  Monom (1, 0)]  -- 2*x + 1`

Your task is to replace `???` in the definition of `diff` with code that can take something like 2) and produce something like 3).